# Force popup window on top of web application

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'd like to know if there's a way to always have a certain popup window, if it has been opened, on top of your web application using javascript, I mean only on top of your own web application, putting it on top of everything would be abussive and I'm sure cannot be done, so if the user opens other page or browser my window can be on background but if it's my application the one that's active it should display.

Maybe it can be done with window.focus() but problem is that the window is just generated from one aspx page, so if the user goes to another aspx page I see no way to focus that window even if I declare a global variable, as that variable is only global for the aspx web page it is in.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe there's an alternative solution, such as an iframe in a floating window within the browser's viewport. What kind of problem is this popup meant to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You probably are thinking of a Modal popup, that is a popup that "blocks" anything on the main page as long as it's open.

There are many alternatives: http://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/

but I suggest bPopup, since it's very lightweight and easy to use: http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

Obviously they all need jQuery.

However if  you really just want a popup on top of everything else, you could just change its `z-index` value to a very large number (like 9000 or even 'over 9000').

Or to be absolutely sure the popup z-index value is the greatest, you could use this function to find the max z-index on the page then going one over:

```
function maxZ() {
    var maxZ = Math.max.apply(null,$.map($('body > *'), function(e,n){
           if($(e).css('position')=='absolute')
                return parseInt($(e).css('z-index'))||1 ;
           })
    );
    return maxZ;
}
```

Source: http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-find-highest-z-index-page/

Note the `$(e).css('z-index')` part that is the right way to read the z-index and you can set it with `$(e).css('z-index', 9000)`.